# How to make a bootable ISO from a bootable DVD using the command line?

Tags: dvd, iso

I need to create an image to be able to mount the install DVD inside virtualbox in order to boot and install Windows.

**Important**: I need to do it using the command line.

I tried with **genisoimage** [as suggested here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning) and created an image using the command below but it turned out not bootable...

```
genisoimage -r -J -o cd_image.iso /cdrom
```

What I need is to RIP my original bootable DVD into a bootable IMAGE that I can mount in virtualbox.

So I thought I would ask how to A) convert that ISO file into a bootable one or B) re-create the ISO making it bootable with genisoimage or other command.

Comment: I want to create an ISO image file so that I can boot a virtualbox machine from it. I don't want a USB stick.. I will check the mentioned question.

Comment: I need to do it from the command line. Will try to find info with `dd`

Comment: Use the original iso.  How to create a custom windows install image is off topic here.

Comment: @psusi There is no original ISO in this case; the OP has a Windows installation CD/DVD. Furthermore, it's very unlikely this is off-topic, as it's really a question about how to rip a CD to an ISO while maintaining DOS/Windows style boot information. And considering that we actually have [an open and highly upvoted question about how to create USB media for installing Windows (from Ubuntu)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu), this question would probably be on-topic even if it *were* specific to installing Windows (which it is not).

Comment: @EliahKagan, the original disc *is* the original iso.  You just copy it rather than generating a new iso using the files copied off the disc.

Comment: @psusi I had the oiginal media but my computer does not have a DVD tray. So I needed a way to make an IMAGE from that media. I will try to improve my question to make it more on-topic.

Comment: What?  Obviously you need a drive to read the disc.

Comment: @psusi Obviously there's two computers here, one of which has an optical drive. Also, most people use "iso" to mean "iso image file." It's rare and probably incorrect to call a physical disc with ISO-9660 compliant data written to it "an iso." Besides the answer that's already here, [your comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/484182/how-to-make-a-bootable-iso-image-from-a-bootable-dvd-using-the-command-line?noredirect=1#comment645850_484182), which is not specific to installing Windows, itself goes a long way toward answering this. Maybe this is a duplicate; I don't think it's off-topic.

Comment: @EliahKagan, in that case yes, it's a dup... shame it won't let you change your vote.

Comment: I can still report or delete. Duplicate of what question?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing off-topic about this question. Reopening.

Comment: @Braiam I re-edited the question because I had to do it from the command line and the marked duplicate answer does not address that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/creating-a-bootable-iso-with-dd-642156/) how to do it using the `dd` command and as far as I can tell it will work for any bootable media.

The command below created a bootable DVD image of my Windows 7 installation disc from the Ubuntu command line:

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=/output/path/forYourImage.iso bs=2k
```

**Note 1**: the generated image will only be bootable **if the source media is bootable**.

**Note 2**: in my case, since I was on a headless server, I first used `sudo lshw -c disk` to find out where on `/dev/` my cdrom drive was located.

**Note 3**: also in my case, the cdrom was not mounted so I had to mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /cdrom`

Comment: Smoke and mirrors: you can just `cp /dev/cdrom /output/path/forYourImage.iso`. There is no dark art being mastered by `dd`.

Answer (score 3):

To create a bootable ISO image, you have to specify to the command that you want this. By default, the ISO image you will create won't be bootable.

With `genisoimage`, you can use the following command line : `genisoimage -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/isolinux.cat -r -J -o cd_image.iso /cdrom`

Assuming that a directory called `isolinux` has been created under the root of your source directory from which you create the ISO file.

The file **isolinux.cat** will be created by the command, this is a catalog needed for the boot loader.
The file **isolinux.bin** is the image of a bootloader, valid for a CD or DVD. These images are available in the **syslinux** package. Check that you have this package installed, if not perform

> sudo apt-get install syslinux-common

Under `/usr/share/syslinux` you will find a predefined bootload, the file `isolinux.bin`.

More info on [the official web site of Syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX) (generic Linux information)

Comment: @EgyptBeast For the future: no need to leave a comment *inside* the text.  That's what the comment field is for!  ;-)